# Trigger event upon hiding BottomSheetModalLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

How can I trigger calling a function when the user clicks outside the ModalBottomSheetLayout, effectively hiding it?

One solution I've found is to implement a LaunchedEffect with the state, but this only changes after it has been hidden, whereas I would like it to happen immediately as the Modal is hiding.

```
val bottomSheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden)
LaunchedEffect(bottomSheetState.isVisible) {
    if (!bottomSheetState.isVisible) {
        doWork()
    }
}

ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        sheetState = bottomSheetState,
        sheetContent = {
            Text("Lorem Ipsum")
        }
) {
    Text("hello worled")
}
```

Comment: you can use `bottomSheetState.targetValue` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use LaunchedEffect but listen to the value of the `ModalBottomSheetState.currentValue`

```
LaunchedEffect(modalBottomSheetState.currentValue) {
                when (modalBottomSheetState.currentValue) {

                    ModalBottomSheetValue.Hidden -> {
                        // Do what you need with a hidden state
                    }

                    ModalBottomSheetValue.Expanded -> {
                        // Do what you need with Expanded state
                    }

                    ModalBottomSheetValue.HalfExpanded -> {
                        // Do what you need with a HalfExpanded state
                    }
                }
```

You can trigger an action at `half expanded` so it doesn't wait until all the bottom sheet is hidden.

Note that his state is only enabled if the height of the bottom sheet is more than 50% of the screen height.